# .NET 4.0 app on .NET 4.5.2 Configuration Error

Tags: .net

I have a .NET 4.0 WCF Service hosted on a machine running .NET 3.5 Compact and .NET 4.5.2.

Whenever I try to run the service I get a `Configuration Error` with the following message:

`Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.`

```
Line 2:  <configuration>
Line 3:    <system.web>
Line 4:      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

I thought 4.5.x frameworks were a replacement for 4.0. How can this be resolved?

Comment: It sounds like your application pool is set to run on 2.0/3.5 framework instead of 4.0/4.5. It's also quite possible that you don't have ASP.NET 4/4.5 registered at all.

Comment: Duh, right! Totally forgot to check the app pool. Thats it, thanks @Luaan